# Flutter container transform

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I wanna transform and pin top right my container when scroll. I show in image. How can I do this ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

first you will need to use either a state management method or the setState() method. You can do this with an if of two cases (true / false). finally have int values ​​with a height and width that control this condition. If you want to add it in an animation, the codes below will help you.

```
 AnimatedContainer(
                width: width,
                height: height.value,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kAffirmativeColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,)
```